# rasa x not running after upgrade rasa

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa, rasa-x

I did `pip install -U rasa`

Now I get this error with rasa x

> rasa.core.exceptions.StoryParseError: Invalid story format. Failed to parse '## happy path
>   * latest_mobiles
>       - brand_form
>       - form{"name": "brand_form"}
>       - form{"name": "null"}'
>   Error: Error in line 2: 'Domain' object has no attribute 'parse'

Comment: which version of rasa it is, can you provide some more details

Answer (score 0):

The syntax to call FormActions seems to be incorrect to me.
Replace it with

```
- brand_form
- form{"name":"brand_form"}
- form{"name":null}
```

notice null doesn't have parentheses.